# Mudando URL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoal tenho um sistema de paginação que a cada página ele puxa um conteúdo do banco de dados.

Nesse caso ele puxa a ID "ID de cada elemento do meu banco", estou tentando mudar para que ele pegue o campo " Nome " do meu banco de dados mas não estou conseguindo, teria como alguém me explicar ?

```
<?php
$Pagina = (isset($_GET['cadastro'])) ? $_GET['cadastro'] : 1;
$BancoD = "SELECT * FROM cadastro ORDER BY id ASC";

$Val = mysqli_query($conexao,$BancoD);
$Total = mysqli_num_rows($Val);
$Quantidade = 1;
$NumeroPagina = ceil($Total/$Quantidade);
$PaginaInicial = ($Quantidade*$Pagina)-$Quantidade;

$Bancod = "SELECT * FROM cadastro ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $PaginaInicial,$Quantidade";
$Val= mysqli_query($conexao,$BancoD);
$Total = mysqli_num_rows($Val);

while ($NovelPost = mysqli_fetch_array($Val)){
    echo $NovelPost['Nome'];
    echo $NovelPost['Idade'];
    echo $NovelPost['Cidade'];
    echo $NovelPost['Codigo'];              
}
?>
```

Já tentei usar o `WHERE Nome=$Pagina` mas não consegui.

Comment: Quais dados existem na coluna `nome`?  Jose, Paula, Ana, Maria etcc? `$Pagina` pelo que se vê no código retorna um numero, portanto esse `WHERE Nome=$Pagina` não rola. Para pegar pelo nome tem que passar algum ´nome` via POST ou GET e fazer a consulta com esse dado recebido.

Comment: Consegui, mto obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Como foi que fez?

Comment: Como foi que fez? A segunda consulta não está servindo para nada, está lá de bobeira.

Comment: Eu fiz um script novo, porém peguei a url atual com um GET dps só mandei buscar no banco de dados os valores existente do GET.

`<?php
   require_once('conexao.php');

   $LK = $_GET['LK'];

   $Valor_link = "SELECT Nome,Data,Codigo FROM Cadastro WHERE Nome LIKE '$LK'";
   $resultado_encontrado = mysqli_query($conex, $Valor_link);
   
   if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado_encontrado) <= 0){
    echo "Nada foi encontrado";
   }
   else{
    while ($Cad = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_encontrado)){
     echo '<h2>'.$Cad['Nome'].'</h2>';
    }
   }
  ?>`